# How to store byte array field in Elasticsearch using spring data elasticsearch without indexing?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to store byte array field in Elasticsearch without indexing it. I'm using spring data elasticsearch module. What is the right way? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct fieldtype in Elasticsearch for this would be the [*binary* field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html). Alas this is currently not available in Spring Data Elasticsearch, I just created [a Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-621) for this.

Even if the *binary* field type were implemented, you still would need to base64 encode the binary data, so that in Elasticsearch it would be stored in a text representation.

Until this *binary* field type is implemented, you might try to use a field definition like:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, index = false)
private String base64Data;
```

Like with the *binary* field type you have to encode your data as base64 String and decode it when it's coming back from the search. Even better wer if you could add the `doc_values=false` argument to `@Field` annotation, to have support for this, there is currently a PullRequest open, but which is not yet ready to be merged; not sure, if this will make it into the 3.2.0 release.

**Edit March 2020:**

in version 4.0.0, you can user the `FieldType.Binary` type together with a `byte[]` and this will be converted to a base64 encoded string (and back again).